# Android Studio does not install app after using the Internal Test Track version

Tags: android-studio, adb, google-play-console

I've been working on my app for a while now and recently uploaded it to the Google Play Console's Internal Test Track. I installed my app via Google Play Store and it worked fine.

But if I now try to install an updated debug version via Android Studio directly it just launches my main activity without installing the changed app.

**What I've tried:**

- Uninstalling app and running in via AS: `"Error: Activity class {...} does not exist."`
- Restarting phone
- Restarting AS
- Reconnecting phone
- Uninstalling app via AS (`gradlew uA`)
- Uninstalling app via app manager
- Invalidating AS cache
- Cleaning / rebuilding project
- Disabling `Skip installation if APK has not changed` in Run Configurations -> Miscellaneous
- Increasing version number

**What may cause it:**

- The Internal Test Track version is signed, but the key is kept by Google
- <s>The app is not selected as 'App to debug', but the dialog to choose one, does not offer it</s>

How can I install my unreleased version via Android Studio directly again?

Thanks in advance. *-Minding*

Comment: I reported this behaviour as a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124543732

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**QUICKFIX**

The "Gradle Aware" task was missing for some reason. To fix it "Run" > "Edit configurations" > "+" > "Gradle-aware Make" > "OK" (leave the field empty) and restart.

The Android Studio team is still investigating why this happened.

---

**Old answer / Workaround**

Using the ADB to directly uninstall the release version and installing the debug version worked, **but you have reinstall the app for every change!** <strike>A better solution would still appreciated.</strike>

- Build your project's debug APK
- Enter the following into the terminal:

`adb uninstall MY_PACKAGE_NAME`

`adb install -r ./mobile/build/outputs/apk/debug/mobile-debug.apk`

If you get `"adb" not found.` use `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb` instead.

- Select the app to be `App to debug` in the device's developer options.

Hope this help. *-Minding*